# Deleting DB entries in PostgreSQL seems to go into infinite loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am recording tracks with GPS and send thos to my Postgre DB, then I want to delete the leading and trailing measurements where speed = 0. I tried it like this:

```
while track.measurements.last.speed == 0
      track.measurements.last.destroy
end
```

(Same for track.measurements.first). When this piece of code is executed everything just stalls without any errors. What I found by debugging and going in step by step is that it repeatedly switches between these two lines:

(rdb:102) s
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/associations.rb:156
association = association_instance_get(name)

```
(rdb:102) l
[151, 160] in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/associations.rb
   151      # :nodoc:
   152      attr_reader :association_cache
   153  
   154      # Returns the association instance for the given name, instantiating it if it doesn't already exist
   155      def association(name) #:nodoc:
=> 156        association = association_instance_get(name)
   157  
   158        if association.nil?
   159          reflection  = self.class.reflect_on_association(name)
   160          association = reflection.association_class.new(self, reflection)
(rdb:102) s
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/associations.rb:170
@association_cache[name.to_sym]

(rdb:102) l
[165, 174] in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/associations.rb
   165      end
   166  
   167      private
   168        # Returns the specified association instance if it responds to :loaded?, nil otherwise.
   169        def association_instance_get(name)
=> 170          @association_cache[name.to_sym]
   171        end
   172  
   173        # Set the specified association instance.
   174        def association_instance_set(name, association)
```

Sadly this means nothing to me. Can anyone help here?

Comment: Do any of the measurements in the middle have the possibility of a zero speed?

Comment: Yes, that's why I cant just delete all measurements which have zero speed

Comment: This would not help with old records but I would recommend not creating any measurement records until you have detected the first measurement that has speed > 0. Just a thought...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well somehow this seems to interfere with some associations, I don't know why exactly this did not work, but here is my solution that works for now:

```
    #remove standing time from beginning and end
    for i in 0..self.measurements.length-1
      if self.measurements[i].speed == 0
        self.measurements[i].destroy
      else
        break
      end
    end

    for i in (self.measurements.length-1).downto(0)
      if self.measurements[i].speed == 0
        self.measurements[i].destroy
      else
        break
      end
    end
```

Thank you for helping!

Comment: another issue: I know I should use .destroy when deleting something, but this messed up a lot of stuff, while .delete worked just fine

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that `track.measurements.last` is not queried for each loop so your code is an infinite loop:

```
while true
track.measurements.last.destroy
end
```

You could do a variation of this but it isn't particularly efficient:

```
last_is_zero = true
while last_is_zero 
  if track.measurements.last.speed == 0
    track.measurements.last.destroy
  else
    last_is_zero = false
  end
end
```

Comment: Updated after reading your comment of potential zero values in the middle.

Comment: This makes sense, but it still is not working. When debugging I can't even destroy the last measurement manually:
irb(#<Trip:0xb5ae8f0c>):011:0> self.measurements.last.destroy
=> #<Measurement id: 4086, created_at: "2013-06-18 10:26:15", updated_at: "2013-06-18 10:26:15", trip_id: 18>
irb(#<Trip:0xb5ae8f0c>):012:0>

It does not get destroyed there. SO I guess the problem is not the loop

Comment: Maybe it is because this all happens when the measurements are uploaded by POST request. When I use this loop in rails console everything works fine.